# Files and folders not visible, but accessible - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: filesystem

There are some files and folders that are not visible to me in the file explorer nor in the terminal.
I think it only affects some "hidden" files and folders, starting with a dot, but not all of them. For example, the folder `~/.aws` and the file `~/.zshrc`. I see other hidden files but not those. I can navigate to `~/.aws` from the navigation bar (Ctrl+L), and typing it manually, but it won't autocomplete. Same thing in the terminal, I can `cd` into the folder, or `vim` the file, but I can't use autocomplete. This makes me think it is not an issue with Nautilus, but I'm not sure.

I have tried to create a bootable Ubuntu USB drive, boot from it, and check / repair the filesystem from that, that did not reveal any issue, or fix anything. It was working last week.

What might have happened in between is while solving an issue (with the graphics driver), I also booted from a USB, did some checks and repairs on the drive (it was showing an issue with the bootable partition of my main drive), and decrypted the home folder to retrieve some data, could it be linked?

Comment: Maybe it is time indeed to have your file system checked and repaired.

Comment: How do I do that? From the bootable USB it does not change anything

Comment: If you have the live USB, then the easiest way will be to use the utility "Disks" from within the live session.

Comment: Unfortunately this is what I had already tried, without success

Comment: I'm wondering if this is actually the cause of the issue, attempting to repair the disk, but as the home folder is encrypted, I think I've read it could cause issues, could that be it?